# Meaning of "Numbers"

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I am kind of confused about the meaning of the noun "*numbers*" in this [piece](http://online.wsj.com/articles/hong-kong-government-seeks-to-wait-out-protesters-1412149487):

> Some anxiety that had built around the protests ahead of Wednesday, a holiday to celebrate the founding of the People’s Republic of China, eased as the day wore on and protests in many parts of Hong Kong took on a festive tone, with some demonstrators offering free haircuts and massages. As on other days, ***numbers shrank in the midday heat*** and swelled again as evening approached.

I've already checked dictionaries, but I cannot quite pinpoint the correct definition of "*numbers*" to use.

Comment: "numbers" here refers to "the number of people". In these usages "numbers" would be understood as more than one (demonstrator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster, one of the definitions of "number" is "a person who is identified by a number and not treated in a personal or friendly way". Thus "numbers" can mean, among other things, "group of people that are related to impersonally", or just "many individuals in a group".

Answer (score 1):

Usually in news-style articles you see this, the subject is implied. I found this  [at dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/number)

> 10.
>   numbers.
>
> a considerable amount or quantity; many:
>
> *Numbers flocked to the city to see the parade*.